# How to implement this function in mupad (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to implement the following function. But I dont know how to define a function over a set of variables such as `mu(1)`, `mu(2)`, `mu(3)`,..., `mu(c)`. `c` is a numeric symbol (i.e. it is a parameter of the function, but not an input value):

```
f := (mu(i), i=1..c) -> sum(mu(i)^2,i=1..c)
```

In other words, I want the symbolic form of `f(MU)=norm(MU)^2`, where `MU` is a vector of `1xc` variables.

Thanks

**EDIT**:
In fact, I want to trace the following computation in mupad from [Modeling Uncertainty with Fuzzy Logic: With Recent Theory and ...](http://books.google.com/books?id=XNHzqfvMTbwC&pg=PA323&dq=fuzzy+c-means+lagrange&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TL-9UKqFDoui8ATEx4DIBA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=fuzzy%20c-means%20lagrange&f=false).

I have also attached the picture of computation steps (of fuzzy c-means).

[image: calculations]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the question (how `c` can be a parameter, but not an input value?)

```
>> f = @(mu) sum(mu .^ 2); % applied on all elements
>> g = @(mu, c) sum(mu(1 : c) .^ 2);  % applied on mu(1:c)
>> f(1:3)

ans =

    14

>> g(1:10, 3)

ans =

    14
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need them in a symbolic format. The code is in MATLAB, where mupad (a toolbox for symbolic processing of matlab) produces symbolic results. The 'c' in a constant which is not knows for now, you can consider it as a numeric symbol (parameter)

Comment: @remo, unfortunately I don't have any experience with symbolic Matlab. But may I ask, why do you think that you need symbolic? For such optimization problem you can use Matlab's optimization tools like `fmincon()`. Or if you have an analytic solution (which is the case here) just define reasonable data grid and solve it.

Comment: The answer is pretty clear and is similar to the comparison of interpreters vs. compilers. When you solve an equation in symbolic manner, you can save the final solution and forget about the middle computation, however it is not the case for numeric solutions. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

```
f := mu -> _plus(mu[i]^2 $ i=1..nops(mu));
```

Call with a list:

```
f([1,2,3,4])
```

Or, to be able to invoke `f(1,2,3,4)`:

```
f := () -> _plus(args(i)^2 $ i=1..args(0));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the syntax is new for me, I learned it. But how to trace (or regenerate) the computation above.

Comment: I have no idea what the connection between M and K on the left hand side and mu, xk, vi, and lambda on the right hand side is. (From the context, lambda is newly introduced, but the others, I cannot really guess.)

Comment: The computation appears when we want to do a fuzzy clustering, here mu is the membership function, c is the number of clusters (groups), m is a simple value (for example 2), v_i is the centroid of the i-th cluster, n is the dimension of the dataset, and W is the function we want to optimize. I want to change W and trace the computation (using the Lagrangian multiplier). Thanks